# Navigation on Area 51 is confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, navigation

When I find myself on my user page, or browsing through the faq / badges and so on. I find it a little bit confusing to get back to the proposal list.

Can navigation elements some how be improved so you do not feel lost when you hit a sub section? (bread crumbs ? navigation tab ? )

For example, this is how user profile page looks like:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

This was completed at some unknown time and bread crumbs were added:

> [image]